# Resize the tensor to a specific shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `(1,32,32,3)`. I want to reshape it with shape `(16,8,8,3)`. Is there any way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):

```
>>> a = tf.random.uniform((1,32,32,3))
>>> a.shape
TensorShape([1, 32, 32, 3])
>>> b = tf.reshape(a,(16,8,8,3))
>>> b.shape
TensorShape([16, 8, 8, 3])
```

This works as long a there is the same number of elements in your tensor in the reshaped form.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to reshape the Tensor from the given shape of `(1,32,32,3)` to `(16,8,8,3)` it can be done using `tf.reshape`. It is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape).